# Looping through MySQL database with multiple browser instances

Tags: mysql, loops, concurrency, transactions, multiple-instances

I have a list of URLs (of pictures) in a MySQL table and I'm writing some code in Coldfusion to download these and store them on the server.

My table looks something like this:

### picture

id
url
status (0:not in process, 1: in process, 2: done downloading)

My page has a simple index loop, "i" from 1 to 100. Each time it picks a record with status = 0, downloads it and sets that record to status = 2. Everything works fine when I have 1 browser window running.

But to make things go faster I want to run multiple browser instances. When I do that though the 2nd browser page doesn't process anything until the 1st one is completely done.

What do I need to do to be able to run multiple browser instances? They all run at the same time, and they never pick up the same picture.id.

Some more info on my setup:

. picture table uses InnoDB engine
. max_user_connections is set to 0; both global and user level

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Based on your description it isn't clear why the second browser downloads them at all.  Don't they have status of 2?  Don't you only download status 0?

Comment: 2nd browser doesn't download the ones the 1st one did. If 1st picks up id:1 then second picks id:2 and first one moves onto 3, second to 4 and so on. That's what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using transactions (implicitly or explicitly)? It appears that there's some lock contention going on.

Here's how I solved a similar issue recently:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT id, url, status FROM urls WHERE status = 0 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
-- Save the id and url in your app
UPDATE urls SET status = 1 WHERE id = [id]
COMMIT;
-- start downloading the URL. You can do a simple update to change the status from 1 to 2 when the download is complete.
```

If the above is wrapped in your loop, it should work correctly, and keep the browsers from downloading the same image simultaneously.

Comment: I was doing it just as you described except one difference. I didn't have the "for update" statement. I added it now, but unfortunately that didn't change anything. 2nd browser window starts loading only after the 1st one is completely done. Feels like a MySQL server level restriction of some sort.

Comment: Are you sure you start processing AFTER the commit? That's the only thing I could think is going on. (the FOR UPDATE just helps protect the record from being read twice). Another option is to remove the transaction stuff all together, and perhaps have the other browser use LIMIT 5,1 or something.

Comment: Just realized that if I run the 2nd browser from another workstation - from a different IP - I'm able to run both browsers at the same time. So I'm convinced that this is some kind of a user level restriction on MySQL Server. I thought having max_user_connections as 0 would take care of this issue. Apparently not.

Comment: The only way that would be a problem if both browsers were trying to share the same connection, which is strange.

Comment: even if I do something extremely simple such as; 
"select id from picture limit 1" query within a loop from 1 to 999 and print the id for each run (it'll all be the same id) - and I run it on 2 browsers, the 2nd browser will start printing results only after 1st browser is done completely. So it's not even an update or a transaction issue. I can't even do a simple select from 2 browsers at the same time.

Comment: maybe this is the answer & it's just the way it is:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236782/can-mysql-support-concurrent-queries-per-connection
all my browser instances use the same DSN hence the same user & connection...